# Visual Studio 2019 Installer crashes after extraction

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to install Visual Studio 2019 Community Version for Unity. But when I open the installer file. It extracts stuff to

> C:\Users(username)\AppData\Local\Temp

In the log file I see this message

> [8/5/2021, 21:21:5] === Logging started: 2021/08/05 21:21:05 ===
> [8/5/2021, 21:21:5] Executable: D:\vs_community__1626322566.1628089410.exe v16.10.31515.178
> [8/5/2021, 21:21:5] --- logging level: standard ---
> [8/5/2021, 21:21:5] Directory 'C:\Users(username)\AppData\Local\Temp\4008442ae7c1f30b10' has been selected for file extraction
> [8/5/2021, 21:21:5] Extracting files to: C:\Users(username)\AppData\Local\Temp\4008442ae7c1f30b10
> [8/5/2021, 21:21:6] Extraction took 187 milliseconds
> [8/5/2021, 21:21:6] Executing extracted package: 'vs_bootstrapper_d15\vs_setup_bootstrapper.exe ' with commandline '  --env "_SFX_CAB_EXE_PACKAGE:D:\vs_community__1626322566.1628089410.exe _SFX_CAB_EXE_ORIGINALWORKINGDIR:D:"'
> [8/5/2021, 21:21:13] The entire Box execution exiting with result code: 0x0
> [8/5/2021, 21:21:13] Launched extracted application exiting with result code: 0xe0434352
> [8/5/2021, 21:21:13] === Logging stopped: 2021/08/05 21:21:13 ===

I do not understand this so please help me.

Comment: have you tried downloading?

Comment: Have you got space on C: AND D: ? The installer appears to be extracting a file on D:

Comment: Yeah I have enough space. I had installed Visual Studio about a month ago but then I deleted it and decided to start over.

Comment: Well 0xe0434352 suggests corrupted .net install

Comment: How you *delete* it. You have to use uninstall feature to remove it.

Comment: @Phil1970. I deleted it from the control panel and completely deleted all VisulStudio Folders from Program Files, Program Data, Program Files (x86) and even Appdata

Comment: @BugFinder. SO how should I fix the .NET installation?

Comment: The online installer usually fails when your system locks down certain areas. Try to create an offline installation folder, and then install from there, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/create-an-offline-installation-of-visual-studio?view=vs-2019

Comment: @LexLi It seems that the error 0xe0434352 suggest a corrupted .NET installation. But still I will try what you are saying.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to solve the problem by repairing the .NET installation but now I am getting this -

> [8/6/2021, 10:32:37] === Logging started: 2021/08/06 10:32:37 ===
> [8/6/2021, 10:32:37] Executable: C:\Users(username)\Downloads\vs_community__1626322566.1628089410.exe v16.10.31515.178
> [8/6/2021, 10:32:37] --- logging level: standard ---
> [8/6/2021, 10:32:37] Directory 'C:\Users()username\AppData\Local\Temp\53a15510ec39c34d6a48f19c' has been selected for file extraction
> [8/6/2021, 10:32:38] Extracting files to: C:\Users\arnav\AppData\Local\Temp\53a15510ec39c34d6a48f19c
> [8/6/2021, 10:32:38] Extraction took 266 milliseconds
> [8/6/2021, 10:32:38] Executing extracted package: 'vs_bootstrapper_d15\vs_setup_bootstrapper.exe ' with commandline '  --env "_SFX_CAB_EXE_PACKAGE:C:\Users(username)\Downloads\vs_community__1626322566.1628089410.exe _SFX_CAB_EXE_ORIGINALWORKINGDIR:C:\Users(username)\Downloads"'
> [8/6/2021, 10:32:47] The entire Box execution exiting with result code: 0x0
> [8/6/2021, 10:32:47] Launched extracted application exiting with result code: **0x1389**
> [8/6/2021, 10:32:47] === Logging stopped: 2021/08/06 10:32:47 ===

This time I am getting a 0x1389 error. I don't know what that means

Comment: Rebuild your PC, honestly these aren't good errors. Why was the .Net Framework install corrupt? Chances are if you fix one thing that will just uncover another problem. Instead of troubleshooting symptoms of the problem I reckon it will be quicker to fix the root cause. A Fresh PC by reinstalling the OS.

Comment: I guess googling your error code was a bit hard. 

I agree with Jeremy reinstall the machine it would be much less time wasted and these are general machine issues not programming issues and are off topic